# Trigger a Logic App to execute for multiple CRM Organizations

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I have an Dynamics CRM environment with multiple organizations configured. I want to create a Logic App that triggers on changes for an entity on multiple of these organizations.

As start I created an Logic App with a normal trigger "When a record is created" in CRM (which is of type ApiConnection). This works only for a single organization. But I want the organization to be dynamic, using a parameter.

So what I did is, create a Logic App with a Recurrence trigger. Add a for each loop that loops over an array of organizations. Inside the loop I call the "When a record is created" trigger as action. The Logic App itself works fine, but the trigger results in the following error:

`{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Call back url is not set as the trigger is being used as an action",
  "source": "dynamicscrmonline-logic-cp-westeurope.logic-ase-westeurope.p.azurewebsites.net",
  "debugInfo": "clientRequestId: 074981e9-dddc-43e0-9293-6e0900a606a6"
}`

Google has no hits on `Call back url is not set as the trigger is being used as an action`.

So, what I'm looking for is either a fix for the above error, or a better/alternative approach to this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can't "call a Trigger".  That's just not how it works.  A Trigger creates a callback for a single endpoint.

If the number of CRM Orgs is manageable, say 5-7, you might be best off with one Logic App for each with it's own Trigger.

Those Trigger Logic Apps would merely call a common Logic App for the actual processing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a HTTP Trigger in one Logic App and Register a webhook in the CRM Orgs...